# Sentence structure in subjunctive passive with modal verb in a subordinate clause

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause, passive

In translators I have found for the following sentence:

> This is something that could have been done differently.
> = Das ist etwas, das anders hätte gemacht werden können.

With this I'm particularly confused as to why 'hätte' is not at the end of the clause and I have found this structure in several translators. Does anyone know why *hätte* is not at the end of the clause and if there's a particular rule for this?

Comment: Why do you expect _hätte_ to be at the end? Because of the rule that the finite verb is at the last position in a relative clause? Or are you confused about the order of the auxiliary, the modal verb, the passive auxiliary and the perfect auxiliary in this complex verbal phrase here?

Comment: I expect *hätte* to be at the end because it‘s the finite verb yes. sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: As so often in linguistics: the questino "why" does not make much sense. Yes, in German you can put the *hätte* on that place in the sentence (as well as at the end of the sentence). Both is correct. Now, for the German ear, the version with *hätte* at the end sounds rather clumsy (too many verbs in row), so therefore we would somewhat prefer the *hätte* in separate position. If that's an answer on your "why" question, so be it.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann HA thanks. How would you rephrase my question without using the ambiguous ‚why‘?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think, "why" always refer to a presumption of the asking person. I guess, identifying the false premise of the question is an answer to those kind of questions. It is often hard for the people who ask to exactly identify this premise. But I think, we got it in this case.

Comment: @süßie  I think, your question is actually: "Could somebody please give me some orientation (rules or whatever) in what situation I can put the *hätte* in that position?"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach   I think the ubiquitous *why* question is rooted in that teachers at school when teaching language put the cart before the horse and present to their students rules to follow as were they laws, instead of explaining the linguistic fact that these rules are nothing but boiled down observations of linguistic practice in the community of users. (Yes, I understand that it is easier for teachers to just present rules.) This then leads to students believing that linguistic features are there ***because of*** the rule; and therefore they ask *why* when they just want a rule.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Don't get me wrong. I agree that the why-question is logically problematic. However, I believe, that we can make our best efforts to understand what people actually want to know and what satisfies them: we can try to understand which of their implicit premises are wrong and then point at these premises. That will spread understanding, I hope. Pointing out the logic problem is smart, but it is imho not the most constructive approach in communication. I've done this myself. I just came to believe that this is very abstract and not of help for most people asking here.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I would really love, if you could engage with this question on meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-is-the-problem-with-why-questions-and-how-to-deal-with-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question. I do not have a comprehensive answer. I still try to give an answer, hoping I can shed some light on the grammatical structure. I hope someone more knowledgeable can give you a better answer.

In

> Das ist etwas, das anders hätte gemacht werden können.

*das anders hätte gemacht werden können.* is a relative clause, specifying *etwas*. Your confusion might stem from the fact, that there is the rule:

> In a relative clause the finite verb is in last position.

And the finite verb is actually *hätte*! We can verify this, when we use the phrase in a main clause:

> Etwas hätte anders gemacht werden können.

In the main clause, the finite verb is in second position, and we happily find *hätte* in second position here, and the complex verbal phrase is split by *anders*, so this is verifying that *hätte* is indeed the finite verb here.

So our finite-verb-in-last-position-in-subordinate-clause rule is violated here. This is, because this complex verbal phrase with a modal in perfect is an exception of the rule. Unfortunately, I do not know why this is the case. So, all I can give you is to explain the details of the grammatical structure here and tell you that this structure is an exception. (Since I cannot tell a more general rule which makes this exception appear a more systemically fit, I consider my answer incomplete.)

So let's look at this complex verbal phrase *hätte gemacht werden können*: This is a passive construction (*etwas wird gemacht*) combined with a modal verb (*etwas kann gemacht werden*), which is in Perfekt tense (*etwas hat gemacht werden können*) and on top it is also Konjunktiv mood (*etwas hätte gemacht werden können*).

Let me summarize the relevant exception rules here:

- [In subordinate clauses](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/modalverben/wortposition-modalverbs/), the modal verb is in last position.
- [The structure of modal verbs in passive](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/passiv/passiv-mit-modalverb/) is: Except for Präsens and Präteritum tense, the auxiliary is at the beginning of the complex verbal phrase.

In a comment, [Satish Vasan](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9555/satish-vasan) has mentioned [this very good resource](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#id=Anchor-Ausnahme-35882) (in German) with an overview over the exceptions.

Comment: I think the details of more general rules can be found here:  https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#id=Anchor-Ausnahme-35882.  In particular, the section on "Mehrere Verbformen am Ende
eines Nebensatzes"

Comment: @SatishVasan Thanks for the link! Very good resource. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you both this is really useful! :)

Comment: @SatishVasan Thanks!

Comment: This is trivially wrong in more than one way. If it is correct in some higher order of syntax theory though, I would be surprised. The main clause showing second position finite verb, *das hätte anders gemacht werden können*, differs markedly from the relative clause word order. At best you might hold the adverb *anders* be a constituent of the verbal phrase *anders-machen* (lexically verbal in *ändern*) following difficult rules about seperable verbs, although it might also be cast as akin to the determiner *anderes*, cp. *etwas, das hätte* mir/anders *gemacht werden können, (nicht ihm/so)*